# How to set the yield wait for seconds back to 60 seconds when the player gets hit by an enemy?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically I want to make a player that can transform into demon at will whenever the user press the power-up button however I want the transformation to end after 60 seconds (when the transformation ends I want the player revert back to his original state). I also want the transformation to end if the player gets hit by an enemy. So far I've made this code and it works but I'm having trouble resetting the yield wait for seconds back to 60 seconds when if the player gets hit by an enemy and if the user decided to press the button to transform the player  back into a demon. Can anyone help me with this problem?

In my hierarchy I have my player as the parent and my demon player as the child. A playermovement script attached to the player as well as the transformation script below:

```
  public GameObject demon;
  public BoxCollider2D col;
  public Renderer rend;
  public ParticleSystem par1;
  public static Vector3 target;


    void Start () {
        target = transform.position;
    }

    void Update () {
         target.z = transform.position.z;
    }

    public void DemonCharacter() {
    StartCoroutine (PowerUpCoroutine ());
}

     private IEnumerator PowerUpCoroutine() {

      yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.3f);

      par1.Play (); // particle system animation to cover transformation happening
  par1.transform.position = target;

      yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.2f);

      demon.SetActive (true); // activates demon gameobject

      rend.enabled = false; // deactivate players spriterenderer 

      col.enabled = false;

      yield return new WaitForSeconds (60f);

      demon.SetActive (false); // deactivates demon gameobject

      rend.enabled = true; // activate players spriterenderer

      col.enabled = true;

      par1.Stop ();
   }
```

And on my demon player, I attached this script; 
I works but when the user clicks on the button to transform into a demon the yield waitforseconds doesn't stop, so when the player transform into a demon seconds later the demon player transforms back into the player rather than resetting the yield wait for seconds.

```
    public BoxCollider2D Playercol;
    public Renderer PlayerRend;

void Start()
{

}

void Update ()
{

}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col) {
    if (col.tag == "enemy") {
        demon.SetActive (false);
        PlayerRend.enabled = true;
        Playercol.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You say you're having trouble, but can you make it more clear (tell us) what your code does now and what you actually expect it or want it to do? Also I don't see much of a research effort in your question, can you tell us what you have tried already? Did you search for solutions online? If so, can you tell us what you found and whether or not it was useful to you and why? Maybe also take another look at [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: `var demonRoutine = StartCoroutine(DemonCharacter()); if (takeDamage) { StopCoroutine(demonRoutine); }` Something like that could work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way than what @m.rogalski suggested would be to use a simple float variable as timer:

```
public GameObject demon;
public BoxCollider2D col;
public Renderer rend;
public ParticleSystem par1;
public static Vector3 target;

private float demonTimer;

void Start()
{
    target = transform.position;
    demonTimer = 0.0f;
}

void Update()
{
    target.z = transform.position.z;

    if (demonTimer > 0.0f)
    {
        demonTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (demonTimer <= 0.0f)
        {
            demon.SetActive(false);
            rend.enabled = true;
            col.enabled = true;
        }
    }
}

public void DemonCharacter()
{
    par1.Play();
    par1.transform.position = target;
    demon.SetActive(true);
    rend.enabled = false;
    col.enabled = false;

    demonTimer = 60.0f;
}

public void CancelDemon()
{
    demonTimer = 0.0f;
}
```

*Hope this helps,*

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be for you to modify your `Coroutine` to not use `WaitForSeconds` but use it's own timing calculations.

```
// create the flag indicating interruption
bool _interrupt = false;

// create your coroutine
IEnumerator PowerUpCoroutine()
{
    // set the time you want to hold transformation
    const float TRANSFORMATION_INTERVAL = 60.0f;

    // currently elapsed time 
    float currentlyElapsed = 0.0f;

    // add your logic for pre-transformation 

    while ( currentlyElapsed < TRANSFORMATION_INTERVAL && !_interrupt )
    {
        yield return null;
        currentlyElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
    }

    // add post-transformation logic

    // revert transformation process

    _interrupt = false;
}
```

Now if you run this coroutine calling `StartCoroutine(PowerUpCoroutine());` you can interrupt it setting `_interrupt` flag to `true`. eg :

```
public void Interrupt()
{
    _interrupt = true;
}

// in some update :
if ( gotHitThisFrame == true )
    Interrupt();
```

Comment: You might even get rid of a separate _interrupt flag if you promote currentlyElapsed into a member variable and set currentlyElapsed to TRANSFORMATION_INTERVAL in your Interrupt method.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance in my problem, I really appreciate it  :)